# Can Eclipse parse and use emacs-style meta information in source code?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, coding-style

In emacs, it is possible to start a file off with a line this:

```
/* -*- mode: java; c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*- */
```

This instructs emacs to use 4 spaces for indentation.  I like the idea of storing this coding style meta-information directly and explicitly in the source code.  Are there any options for doing this in other IDEs?  Does eclipse in particular have the ability to configure itself from a line in the emacs format or something equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know: no, Eclipse Formatter won't configure itself when reading emacs instructions in the code.

This is why you can find Emacs plugins like [this one for Ganymede](https://anirudhsasikumar.net/blog/2009.05.01.html) allowing you to quickly open a file on Emacs from Eclipse!

[image]
<sub>(source: [chaosnet.org](http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/imgs/eclipse-emacs.png))</sub>

Comment: Nice!  I like this suggestion for myself, but unfortunately I can't force it on others who stubbornly insist on using the eclipse editor :)